# Using bootstrap switch within dynamically inserted table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [Bootstrap Switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/events.html) within a table row `<tr>` that has been dynamically inserted. The table row html I insert looks like:

```
<tr id="reference"><td>name</td><td></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" class="slider" data-size="mini" checked></td><td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-object-ungroup"></i></a></td><td></td><td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td></tr>
```

and after the insert, I then call `$("#reference input.slider").bootstrapSwitch();` which transforms the simple checkbox into a togglable on/off slider. This all works fine.

The problem I am having is capturing events on the bootstrap switch.

As the row has been added dynamically, I have tried

```
$("#user-area-table tbody").on('click', 'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(evt) {
  console.log('bootstrap switch change');
)};
```

but when an on/off state change occurs, this is never reached.

Using this:

```
$("#user-area-table tbody").on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(evt) {
  console.log('bootstrap switch change');
});
```

I can get on/off events but `$(this)` is simply the `tbody` and I need to determine in which row the on/off was toggled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `evt.target` to get the DOM input element associated with the bootstrap switch. The event data passed into the callback is a jQuery event object, which you can read more about here: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Once you have that element, you can find the row it's contained in like so:

```
$(evt.target).closest("tr");
```

Closest checks the current element and then looks UP the DOM through its ancestors to find the closest element that matches the selector (in this case, the closest TR tag.

Also, the reason this failed:

```
$("#user-area-table tbody").on('click', 'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(evt) {
  console.log('bootstrap switch change');
)};
```

Is because the second argument is actually looking for a *selector*,  but you've passed in an event. There's no element with a tag name of `switchChange` and a class of `bootstrapSwitch`.  Only the first argument to `.on` accepts an event name, which is why your second version is actually called.